# Missing argument in codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

I am new to the codeigniter framework. When I try to load the parameter in codeigniter its showing an error like Missing argument 1. Can anyone please help solve my issue. Here Is my code.

This is My View Code. **In view code i call the parameter in ">Read More**

```
<div class="row m-t-20">
      <?php foreach($show as $row) { ?>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <a href="#"></a>
          <div class="recent-pro-box">
            <div class="pro-img">
            <a href="#"></a>
              <img src="<?php echo base_url()?>uploads/<?php echo $row['img_path']; ?>" alt="" class="img-responsive" /> 
            </div>
            <h2 class="title"><?php echo $row['title'];?></h2>
            <p><?php echo $row['message'];?> ...</p>
            <div class="more-link"><a href="<?php echo base_url("Helen/viewProjects/".$row['p_id']); ?>">Read More</a></div>
          </div>
      </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>
```

Controller code

```
public function viewProjects($id)
    {
        $data['show']=$this->Selection_Model->fullProjects($id);
        $this->load->view('topurl');
        $this->load->view('nav');
        $this->load->view('fullProjects',$data);
        $this->load->view('footer');
    }
```

Model Code

```
 public function fullProjects($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
      $this->db->where('p_id',$id);
    $this->db->from('projects');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->row_array();
    return $result;
    }
```

Final view code

```
<div class="col-md-7 ab-text">
    <?php foreach($show as $row) { ?>
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <a href="#"></a>
          <div class="recent-pro-box">
            <div class="pro-img">
            <p><?php echo $row['message'];?> ...</p>
          </div>
      </div>
    <?php }?>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: check  `$show` using `print_r($show)` and  verify that `p_id` exists in the top most code snippet

Comment: @deep i check it like that its showing same error ... its showing the missing arguments 1

Comment: change to  `return $query->result_array();` in `fullProjects($id)` model  and repeat `print_r($show)` and see

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your view.Not need to use `foreach` loop.Beacuse in codeigniter `row_array` result set is used to fetch only first matched row. try like this..

```
<div class="col-md-7 ab-text">
      <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
          <a href="#"></a>
          <div class="recent-pro-box">
            <div class="pro-img">
            <p><?php echo $show['message'];?> ...</p>
          </div>
      </div>
</div>
</div>
```

**OR**

If you want to use `foreach` loop.

In model change

```
$result = $query->row_array();
```

TO

```
$result = $query->result_array();
```

For more see docs [Codeigniter Result Sets](https://www.codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/results.html)

Comment: i check it like that its showing Missing argument 1

Comment: use `result_array` in model  and `foreach` loop in view.

Comment: but if you use `row_array` in model no need `foreach` loop in view.

Comment: better way is use `row_array` in case of `where` condition for matching row and for matched row `selection`.

Comment: @Anto Alexander glad to help you.best of luck ahead.

Answer (score 0):

All the code's are fine, except one line in Model. Your model should be

```
function fullProjects($id){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('p_id',$id);
    $this->db->from('projects');
    $query = $this->db->get();
    $result = $query->result_array(); # Changed 
    return $result;
}
```

---

> > > If you're accessing array data with this pattern `$row['message'];`, **You must use the array as objective array** like this `$query->result_array();`

Comment: for single selection we can use $query->row_array();

Comment: No change if you used `result_array` too